# Equation Of A Curved Surface

Tags: geometry

How Shall i find an equation of a curved surface? Or is there a mathematical formula for it?

I have 4 points (Vector3f). By connecting them, i make a surface, when the edges that are used to create that face are lines, i can easily make them out. But when it comes to arc, the edges are curved and iam struggling to find out if a point exists on that surface or not.

The approach of splitting that face into triangles and checking leads to over consumption of time. Please suggest me a Best Way To Do So....